# check if selected dates are from the same week javascript

Tags: javascript, date, compare

How to find the given dates are from the same week using javascript?

like if i give dates like, `the week starts SUNDAY`

the below dates fall between `(12 July 2015 to 18 July 2015)`

```
07/13/2015 
07/14/2015 
07/15/2015 
07/16/2015 
07/20/2015
```

in the above list `20` does not follow on the week and it falls on the next week.

would some one help me on this?

I also would like to find the same check for to see if the given dates `are same date` like

```
07/13/2015 
07/13/2015 
07/13/2015
07/13/2015 
07/13/2015 
07/13/2015 
07/14/2015
```

in the above all are same date except `14`. so please help me to find `if the given dates are same date.`

```
I am okay to use external lib also
```

Comment: who defines the start of the week

Comment: I guess for US it starts from SUNDAY , pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I mean.. the date.... whether to consider 12 as the start or 19th

Comment: Oh, sorry got it , have to define this from the first date given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the week always starts on Sunday, you could check if they are all in the same week by doing something like this:

```
function getMinAndMax(dates) {
    var result = {};
    for (var index in dates) {
        var thisDate = dates[index]
        ,   dateParts = thisDate.split(/\//)
        ,   fullDate = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[0] - 1, dateParts[1]);
        if(!result['max'] || fullDate > result['max']) {
            result['max'] = fullDate;
        }
        if(!result['min'] || fullDate < result['min']) {
            result['min'] = fullDate
        }
    }
    return result;
}
function isSameWeek(dates) {
    var minAndMax = getMinAndMax(dates)
    ,   dayOfWeek = {}
    dayOfWeek['min'] = minAndMax['min'].getDay();
    dayOfWeek['max'] = minAndMax['max'].getDay();
    if(minAndMax['max'] - minAndMax['min'] > 518400000 || dayOfWeek['min'] > dayOfWeek['max']) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

To use the above function, you would do:

```
var datesArray = [
    '07/13/2015'
,   '07/14/2015'
,   '07/15/2015'
,   '07/16/2015'
,   '07/10/2015'
];
isSameWeek(datesArray); // false

var datesArray2 = [
    '07/15/2015'
,   '07/14/2015'
,   '07/15/2015'
,   '07/15/2015'
,   '07/13/2015'
];
isSameWeek(datesArray2); // true
```

To see if all the dates are the same, you could include the `getMinAndMax` function declared earlier and then do:

```
function areAllDatesSame(dates) {
    var minAndMax = getMinAndMax(dates);
    return minAndMax['min'] == minAndMax['max']
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
var datesArray = [
    '07/13/2015'
,   '07/14/2015'
,   '07/15/2015'
,   '07/16/2015'
,   '07/13/2015'
];
areAllDatesSame(datesArray); // false

var datesArray2 = [
    '07/13/2015'
,   '07/13/2015'
,   '07/13/2015'
,   '07/13/2015'
,   '07/13/2015'
];
areAllDatesSame(datesArray2); // true
```

Comment: Moishe Lipsker +1 for the effort and i got what i wanted, also would you please update code to find whether the given dates are same date? Thank you

Comment: Would you like a separate function that checks if all of the dates are the same or if any are the same?

Comment: Moishe Lisker separate function would be fine to check all of the dates are the same.

Comment: Moishe Lisker, if the array has one date or if the array has sames only then the above method fails, some times the array might have same date more than once or the array might have only one date

Comment: So you want to know if there is at least one duplicate date (not only when all are the same)?

Comment: Yes the array might have one or many date which may or may not fall on the same week, TRUE- if the date(s) in the array are from same week, FALSE- if the date(s) in the array are not from the same week. I am sorry to disturb you

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are asking for. The first function checks if the dates are in the same week. The second checks if all of the dates are the same exact. You are talking about the second one, right?

Comment: You want the second function to return true if at least one date is within same week as another date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83286/discussion-between-tony-and-moishe-lipsker).

Comment: @ Moishe Lipsker also samedate validaton fails if i send same date more than one time, Please help

Comment: I changed the function around a bit after realizing that I wasn't covering all cases. Please let me know if you have any other questions/problems here.

Comment: thank you for the help, sure will check and let you know the results

Comment: sorry for the late reply and it worked as i wanted, could you please clarify what is this number about 518400000? Thanks

Comment: 6 days in millseconds = 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 518400000. We are checking if max day is more than 6 days greater than the min day.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be using using a library like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/query/is-same) which is only 2kb.

In dayjs you can use the [isSame()](https://day.js.org/docs/en/query/is-same) function

Example:

```js
dayjs().isSame('2021-10-09', 'week')
```

Note: week starts from Sunday. Don't forget to make necessary changes if you want Monday as the day 1 of the week.